# how to join dynamic table and table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `Phone` and `Name`.
Table `Name` contain two fields `Name` and `PhoneNo`.
Table `Phone` contain `PhoneNo` and `call duration`.
Table Name

```
Name     PhoneNo.

A         1111

B         2222

C         3333
```

And Data in Phone Table

```
PhoneNo        CallDuration

1111            30

5555            40

6666            30

1111            20

6666            10

2222            5
```

Result should be a table the will contain two column `Caller` and `occurrence`.  If `caller` exists in `Name` table then her or his `Name` should be there in `Caller` column and no of times it called(from `Phone` table) otherwise `Number` should appear in the `caller` column.
Result of following example should be like this

```
Caller     Ocucrnce

A             2

B             1

5555          1

6666          2
```

I have tried this but now I don't know how to check whether number is in name table or not

```
select PhoneNo,COUNT(*) as CALLER from PhoneNo GROUP BY PhoneNo
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself, or do you just expect us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select
    PhoneNo = isnull(n.name, p.PhoneNo),
    Occurence = count(*)
from phone p
left join name n
    on n.PhoneNo = p.PhoneNo
group by
    p.phoneNo, n.name
```

**EDIT**
To include `C`, try this:

```
select
    PhoneNo = isnull(n.name, p.PhoneNo),
    Occurence = count(p.phoneNo)
from phone p
full join name n
    on n.PhoneNo = p.PhoneNo
group by
    p.phoneNo, n.name
```

Comment: In this query 'C' user records come that is not needed.

Comment: @Navneet No it doesn't, it returns the desired result

Comment: What if I want those names also which are not present in Phone Table. Like in my example 'C'. In final result 'C' is also present with Occernce as '0'.                                                                               Final Result should be like this                                                        Caller     Ocucrnce

A             2

B             1

5555          1

6666          2                                                         C              0

Answer (score 0):

try this: Simple Join With `Count` can work here.Count will Count occurrences

```
select case when ph.Name is NULL then cal.PhoneNo  else ph.Name end 
,COUNT(*) as Occrnce
 from PhoneNo ph left join CallDuration cal
on ph.PhoneNO=cal.PhoneNo
```

Comment: In this query Caller No not come.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT   isnull(Caller     ,PhoneNo) as Caller
        ,COUNT(*) AS CALLER 
FROM     PhoneNo AS p
            LEFT JOIN NameTable AS n ON p.PhoneNo        = n.PhoneNo        
GROUP BY PhoneNo,Caller
```

Grouping by PhoneNo, and also checking if there is any occurrence in the name table by using a [left](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) join...

Comment: In this query Caller name not come.

Comment: You have no information for caller name in your schema... We do not have sufficient information

Comment: This is not my Question but please see the desired Output .

And callerName Means Name Field.

Comment: This won't compile, you need to specify *which* of the two PhoneNo columns to use. If you use the one from the Names table you'll miss the entries without names

Answer (score 0):

To get the names you need to join the results of your query with the `Name` table, eg:

```
SELECT ISNULL(n.Name,p.PhoneNo) as Caller, Occurences
FROM (SELECT PhoneNo, COUNT(*) AS Occurences 
      FROM Phone 
      GROUP BY PhoneNo) p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Name n ON p.PhoneNo=n.PhoneNo
```

or you can just join the two tables then group by `Phone.PhoneNo` and 'Name.Name` like wewesthemenace suggested:

```
select
    PhoneNo = isnull(n.name, p.PhoneNo),
    Occurence = count(*)
from phone p
left join name n
    on n.PhoneNo = p.PhoneNo
group by
    p.phoneNo, n.name
```

In both cases the result is what you want